# How can I NOT truncate a long int/float when printing in Python

Tags: python, printing, long-integer

I have a long int and I don't want it to be truncated when I print it or convert it to a string.

The following does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
b = pd.Series({"playerid": 544911367940993}, dtype='float64')
print("%s" % b['playerid'])
print(str(b['playerid'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to print it out as in the OP, you can just use the `%d` format string

```
In [5]: print('%d' % b['playerid'])
544911367940993
```

You can also use the format() function:

```
In [25]: x = '{:.0f}'.format(b['playerid'])
In [26]: x
Out[26]: '544911367940993'
```

Comment: Your solution is a lot more elegant than the one I've found before by jreback, I accept your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Not the printing truncates your long int, nor the formatting using `"%s"`:

```
>>> "%s" % 12345678901234567898012345678901234567890
'12345678901234567898012345678901234567890'
```

So I guess that passing it into `pd.Series()` and/or getting it from that object by writing `b['playerid']` does any truncation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by jreback:

```
In [75]: b.apply(lambda x: x.__repr__())
Out[75]: 
playerid    544911367940993.0
dtype: object

In [77]: b.apply(lambda x: "%.0f" % x)
Out[77]: 
playerid    544911367940993
dtype: object
```

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3542